# Как подключить css в tpl шаблон

Tags: css, шаблоны, шаблонизаторы, tpl

Не выходит подключить css стиль к tpl шаблону. Когда тестировал данный код на линуксе, все вроде бы работало, сейчас пишу такой же код на windows и стили не подключаются к шаблону. Вот собственно сам код подключения css стиля:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
```

Так же пробуя по разному подключать этот стиль, попробовал подключить его в index.php и тогда стиль подключился, но стал выводиться текстом в самом браузере. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите какие ошибки выдал браузер, скорее всего некорректно настроена выдача статики, и вообще, вы мало информации дали, мог бы минуснуть, но сегодня не буду.

Comment: А Вы ещё проверьть вообще по этому адресу что-то выдаётся localhost/css/style.css ?